# Condition Variable POSIX Thread : C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am learning Multithreading. With regard to

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html#SCHEDULING

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


pthread_mutex_t count_mutex     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_var   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;



void *functionCount1();
void *functionCount2();

int  count = 0;

#define COUNT_DONE  10
#define COUNT_HALT1  3
#define COUNT_HALT2  6



main()
{
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;
   pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionCount1, NULL);
   pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionCount2, NULL);



   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

   printf("Final count: %d\n",count);

   exit(0);
}



// Write numbers 1-3 and 8-10 as permitted by functionCount2()

void *functionCount1()
{
   for(;;)
   {
      // Lock mutex and then wait for signal to relase mutex
      pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );



      // Wait while functionCount2() operates on count
      // mutex unlocked if condition varialbe in functionCount2() signaled.

      pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var, &count_mutex );

      count++;

      printf("Counter value functionCount1: %d\n",count);
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

      if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);
    }
}



// Write numbers 4-7



void *functionCount2()
{
   for(;;)
    {
       pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );

       if( count < COUNT_HALT1 || count > COUNT_HALT2 )
       {
          // Condition of if statement has been met.
          // Signal to free waiting thread by freeing the mutex.
          // Note: functionCount1() is now permitted to modify "count".

          pthread_cond_signal( &condition_var );
       }
       else
       {
          count++;
          printf("Counter value functionCount2: %d\n",count);
       }



       pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

       if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);
    }
}
```

I want to know the control flow of the code.

As `pthread_cond_wait - unlocks the mutex and waits for the condition variable cond to be signaled`

What I understood about the control of flow is

1) Thread One,Two are created and thread1 is passed the control (considering Single Core Processor System)

2) When it encounters `pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var, &count_mutex );` in `thread1` routine `void *functionCount1()` - it releases the lock and goes to wait state passing control to `thread2 void *functionCount1()`

3) In `thread2` variable `count` is checked and since it satisfies `count < COUNT_HALT1 || count > COUNT_HALT2` - it signals `thread1` and restarts is to increment `count`

4) `Steps 2 to 3` is repeated which displays `1-3` by `thread1`

5) For `count 4-7` the thread2 is in action and there is no switching between `thread1` and `thread2`

6)For `count 8-10` again `steps 2-3` are repeated.

I want to know whether my understanding is correct? Does `thread1` goes to sleep and `thread2` wakes it up ( i.e threads are switched)  for `count value 1-3 and 8-10` `i.e switching between threads happen 5 times` ?

**EDIT**

My main concern to ask this question is to know if `thread1` will go to `sleep` state when it encounters `pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var, &count_mutex );` and won't be `active` again unless signalled by `thread2` and only then increments `count` i.e. it is not going to increment `1-3` in one go rather for each increment , it has to wait for signal from `thread2` only then it can proceed further

Comment: You seem to have a race between the `count++` and the `if(count >= COUNT_DONE)` lines. Move the if-statement into the critical section to get rid of it.

Comment: I think pthread_cond_signal of functionCount2 will unblock the functionCount1, but functionCount1 will still wait till the mutex is also unlocked by functionCount2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Threads are created. Control is not passed to thread1, it's system scheduler who decides which thread to execute. Both threads are active, both should receive processor time, but the order is not determined. There might be several context switches, you don't really control this.

2) Correct, thread1 comes to waiting state, thread2 continues working. Again, control is not passed explicitly.

3) Yes, thread2 notifies condition variable, so thread1 will awake and try to reacquire the mutex. Control does not go immediately to thread1.

In general you should understand that you can't really control which thread to execute; it's job os the system scheduler, who can put as many context switches as it wants.

UPD: With condition variables you can control the order of tasks execution within multithreading environment. So I think your understanding is more or less correct: thread1 is waiting on condition variable for signal from thread2. When signal is received thread1 continues execution (after it reacquires the mutex). But switching between threads - there might be many of them, 5 is just a theoretical minimum.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, [pthread_yield](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html) can allow your thread to relinquish the CPU

Comment: Consider ideal case where there are only two threads .. and I consider thread1 is passed first control by OS... then the flow I have mentioned will be correct .. My main concern to is to know that does switching takes place in this code from `thread1` to `thread2` for `count 1-2 & 8-10`

Comment: @nogard Of course, his code actually accesses the control variable `count` outside of the sections protected by a mutex.  So it's completely undefined behavior.  Which means we really can't say anything about what might happen.  The entire code is meaningless.

Comment: @SuvP There is no such thing as `pthread_yield`, at least not in Posix.  And what possible useful semantics that it could be given: that the OS will repass through its scheduler?  That still wouldn't mean that the other thread in question would run.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, access to `count` should be syncronized, no doubt. It was already pointed in the comments.

Comment: @JamesKanze. Oh, I wasn't aware it [isn't](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~xleroy/linuxthreads/faq.html) POSIX. I thought everything under `pthread` is POSIX. I just meant to say, a thread can relinquish the CPU and such a function exist for it. (That was my understanding of `pthread_yield`).Its not necessary the other thread would be scheduled to run. The CPU is free to schedule any threads it wants

Comment: @SuvP But where did you hear about `pthread_yield`?  It's not in any of the Posix thread references (like the Butenhof).  (And of course, it doesn't change anything, formally, since the system _could_ reschedule the thread which called it, and the system can reschedule any other time as well.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Butenhof speaks of [`sched_yield`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sched_yield.html). I guess I must have picked `pthread_yield` up from some very old tutorial. Have been searching for the dangerous pdf on my pc since an hour,didnt find it yet

Answer (score 3):

First: get the book by Butenhof, and study it.  The page you
cite is incorrect in several places, and the author obviously
doesn't understand threading himself.

With regards to your questions: the first thing to say is that
you cannot know about the control flow of the code.  That's
a characteristic of threading, and on modern processors, you'll
often find the threads really running in parallel, with one core
executing one thread, and another core another.  And within each
thread, the processor may rearrange memory accesses in
unexpected ways.  This is why you need mutexes, for example.
(You mention "considering single core processing system", but in
practice, single core general purpose systems don't exist any
more.)

Second, how the threads are scheduled is up to the operating
system.  In your code, for example, `functionCount2` could run
until completion before `functionCount1` starts, which would
mean that `functionCount1` would wait forever.

Third, a thread in `pthread_cond_wait` may wake up spuriously.
It is an absolute rule that `pthread_cond_wait` be in a loop,
which checks whatever condition you're actually waiting for.
Maybe something like:

```
while ( count > COUNT_HALT1 && count < COUNT_HALT2 ) {
    pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var, &count_mutex );
}
```

Finally, at times, you're accessing `count` in a section not
protected by the mutex.  This is undefined behavior; *all*
accesses to `count` must be protected.  In your case, the
locking and unlocking should probably be outside the program
loop, and *both* threads should wait on the conditional
variable.  (But it's obviously an artificial situation—in
practice, there will almost always be a producer thread and
a consumer thread.)

Answer (score 2):

In the ideal world, yes, but, in practice, not quite.

You can't predict which tread takes control first. Yes, it's likely to be `thread1`, but still not guaranteed. It is the first racing condition in your code.

When `thread2` takes control, most likely it will finish without stopping. Regardless of how many CPUs you have. The reason is that it has no place to `yield` *unconditionally*. The fact you release `mutex`, doesn't mean any1 can get a lock on it. Its the second racing condition in your code.

So, the `thread1` will print `11`, and that is the only part guaranteed.

Comment: What is the first race condition you talk about? Why thread2 will finish without stopping? I think this is not the case

Comment: @nogard When you create threads (same priorities etc), you can't tell which one starts first. It is undefined. The second race condition is called lock starvation: when you unlock mutex and lock it back quickly enough there is a very low chance another thread would be able to acquire it.

Comment: When you create threads (same priorities etc), you can't tell which one starts first. - Exactly, I fully agree with this. Still it's not race condition.

Comment: Is missing cond_signal a kind of race condition ? Before a thread starts to wait, signal issued by other thread